# Why is the Scss not updating the code in browser?

Tags: css, sass

[image: Inspect Element in browser]

```
Same scss code in file:

section {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 350px 0; //150
    background-size: cover;
    // background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    &.no-hero {
        padding: 150px 0 130px;
    }
    &#slider:not(.bg-inherit) {
        background-color: var(--hero-bg-color);
    }
}


display: inline-block; style.scss:567
```

As you can see all the code I have updated to increase the padding but it does not reflect on my browser or inspect element even though I have made the changes.

Below I have also attached the React Js code linked with the 'section' class, I have done a hard refresh however the code does not change.

```
class Hero extends Component {
    state = {
        data: {}
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            data: initData
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <section className="hero-section">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                            <span>{this.state.data.pre_heading}</span>
                            <h1 className="mt-4">{this.state.data.heading}</h1>
                            <p>{this.state.data.content}</p>
                            {/* Buttons */}
                            <div className="button-group">
                                <a className="btn btn-bordered-white" href="/explore-1"><i className="icon-rocket mr-2" />{this.state.data.btn_1}</a>
                                <a className="btn btn-bordered-white" href="/create"><i className="icon-note mr-2" />{this.state.data.btn_2}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/* Shape */}
                <div className="shape">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 465" version="1.1">
                        <defs>
                            <linearGradient x1="49.7965246%" y1="28.2355058%" x2="49.7778147%" y2="98.4657689%" id="linearGradient-1">
                            <stop stopColor="rgba(69,40,220, 0.15)" offset="0%" />
                            <stop stopColor="rgba(87,4,138, 0.15)" offset="100%" />
                            </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" strokeWidth={1} fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                            <polygon points fill="url(#linearGradient-1)">
                            <animate id="graph-animation" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" dur="2s" repeatCount attributeName="points" values="0,464 0,464 111.6,464 282.5,464 457.4,464 613.4,464 762.3,464 912.3,464 1068.2,464 1191.2,464 1328.1,464 1440.1,464 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,323.3 282.5,373 457.4,423.8 613.4,464 762.3,464 912.3,464 1068.2,464 1191.2,464 1328.1,464 1440.1,464 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,336.6 457.4,363.5 613.4,414.4 762.3,464 912.3,464 1068.2,464 1191.2,464 1328.1,464 1440.1,464 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,323.3 613.4,340 762.3,425.6 912.3,464 1068.2,464 1191.2,464 1328.1,464 1440.1,464 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,263 613.4,290.4 762.3,368 912.3,446.4 1068.2,464 1191.2,464 1328.1,464 1440.1,464 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,263 613.4,216 762.3,329.6 912.3,420 1068.2,427.6 1191.2,464 1328.1,464 1440.1,464 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,263 613.4,216 762.3,272 912.3,402.4 1068.2,373 1191.2,412 1328.1,464 1440.1,464 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,263 613.4,216 762.3,272 912.3,376 1068.2,336.6 1191.2,334 1328.1,404 1440.1,464 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,263 613.4,216 762.3,272 912.3,376 1068.2,282 1191.2,282 1328.1,314 1440.1,372.8 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,263 613.4,216 762.3,272 912.3,376 1068.2,282 1191.2,204 1328.1,254 1440.1,236 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,263 613.4,216 762.3,272 912.3,376 1068.2,282 1191.2,204 1328.1,164 1440.1,144.79999999999998 1440.1,464 0,464; 0,464 0,367 111.6,263 282.5,282 457.4,263 613.4,216 762.3,272 912.3,376 1068.2,282 1191.2,204 1328.1,164 1440.1,8 1440.1,464 0,464;" fill="freeze" />
                            </polygon>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Hero;
```

Comment: You might need to do *HARD REFRESH* using CTRL+F5

Comment: @bhattaraijay05 Nope doesn't make a difference

Comment: place your HTML here

Comment: @Viira If I edit the code on inspect element and increase padding from 150 - 350 px it works fine so it can't be html error?

Comment: No I want to see the structure of your HTML code

Comment: You add the padding to your sections with the  `no-hero` class, this class is not present in your HTML. That's why you can't see it.

Comment: @cloned that class does not effect the padding because it its not called; if i increase the padding of the section class from 150-350 in inspect element it works but not in my code

Comment: @Viira I have added the React code